How to implement generic filter (FILTER CONTROL ) in qdma (Im using dpdk 2020.11 and Alveo U200 card)
I am implementing Generic Filter in QDMA inside DPDK.  I am using DPDK-20.11. I am not able find any documents releated to Generic filter in QDMA driver. Can you please help me to implement the same.
Please let me know what changes to be made so that Generic filter feature is supported in DPDK using QDMA driver.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Thenveer

@Nafiul Alam Fuji ,  Could you please check
